Coupled non-linear stochastic differential equation
Given two stochastic variables $X, Z$ with the same Wiener increment $dW$, I would like to solve the following set of Itô equations:
\begin{align}
    &dX=-\gamma X dt + \frac{g}{1+\kappa Z^2} dW\\
    &dZ=-\kappa Z dt + g dW\\
\end{align}
Specifically, I am only interested in the asymptotic value of the variance ${E}[x^2(t\rightarrow\infty)]$, as the 1st moments vanish ${E}[x]={E}[z]=0$.
My plan for the variance is to get the Itô SDE just by using $d (x^2)=(dx)x+x(dx)+(dx)(dx)$. However, something needs to be done with my non-linear coupling. What it tried is the following:
Define $Y=\frac{1}{1+\kappa Z^2}$. Then, $X$ is linearly coupled to $Y$. However, the SDE of Y looks like this:
\begin{equation}
    dY= \kappa Y (4+Y(g^2(3-4Y)-4)) dt - 2 g Y^2 \sqrt{\frac{1}{\kappa}\left(\frac{1}{Y}-1\right)} dW
\end{equation}
Even this equation seems not to be solvable, as when I try to solve for $\langle Y \rangle$, it depends on higher-order moments $\langle Y^2 \rangle$ and $\langle Y^3 \rangle$.
Is there any way to solve this set of equations? Is it even solvable? Of course, I can numerically simulate the SDE and I get a finite and well-behaved curve, but the analytics seems difficult.

What do you mean "as the first moments vanish"? Do you know for the fact that their expectations at infinity are zero or are you okay assuming they are zero?

It is just that as $\langle dW \rangle=0$ and they are Itô, the process decouples from the noise. Then, its solution goes to 0 when solving for the long-time limit. Still, even if they didn't, I am only interested in its variance.

(Partial answer)
Itô's lemma brings $\mathrm{d}(X^2) = -2\gamma X^2\mathrm{d}t + 2XY\mathrm{d}W + Y^2\mathrm{d}t$, hence $\mathrm{d}\langle X^2 \rangle = -2\gamma\langle X^2 \rangle \mathrm{d}t + \langle Y^2 \rangle\mathrm{d}t$, because $\mathrm{d}W$ isn't correlated with $X$ and $Y$. This latter equation is a standard inhomogeneous first-order linear ODE for $\langle X^2 \rangle$. It is solved with the help of varying parameter method, which leads to $$\langle X^2(t) \rangle = \langle X^2(0) \rangle e^{-2\gamma t} + \int_0^t \langle Y^2(t') \rangle e^{-2\gamma(t-t')} \mathrm{d}t'$$.
But how to determine $\langle Y^2(t) \rangle$. Let's recall that $Z$ is an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process, which is nothing else than the gaussian variable $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu;\sigma^2)$, with $\mu = Z_0e^{-\kappa t}$ and $\sigma^2 = \frac{g^2}{2\kappa}(1-e^{-2\kappa t})$. Then, we have :
$$
\langle Y^2 \rangle = \frac{g^2}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{(z-\mu)^2/2\sigma^2}}{(1 + \kappa z^2)^2} \mathrm{d}z
$$
This integral can be tackled through contour integration and residue computation. The integrand possesses second-order poles at $\pm\frac{i}{\kappa}$.

That answer is great. Just to be clear, this answer is only possible because we are able to formally integrate $X(t)$, right? Otherwise, one really needs to compute the coupled SDE?

Also, after working this out, the integral seems to diverge at t=0 because then $\sigma=0$. How can this problem be avoided?

@J.Agusti   It can be avoided by considering a different initial condition. It is to be noted too that the integral term in $\langle X^2 \rangle$ corresponds to a Laplace transform of $\langle Y^2 \rangle$ (with respect to $t$), which may be computed through the residue of its essential singularity at $t = 0$. Finally, keep in mind that the final result might diverge anyway, because $\langle Y^2 \rangle$ corresponds to the convolution of a gaussian with a sigmoidal curve, which is often divergent. In that case, you will have to conclude that $\langle X^2(t) \rangle \to \infty$.
